In a generative model, how to factorize the likelihood of observing the data using the DAG dependencies?
In Machine Learning, considering a generative model represented by the following Direct Acyclc Graph (DAG):

where:

latent variables are: z0, z1 and tr
observed variables are a, xO, x1

We want to train the model so that we maximize the likelihood of seeing the observations from the latent variables, i.e.:

How to factorize this expression in term of the dependencies of the DAG ?

I have tried the following:

with

and

But now, I am stuck
